# Prometheus alertmanager: Is it possible to decrease the number of alerts?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

Is it possible to decrease the number of alerts?

For example, I have HostHighCpuLoad95

I receive alerts like these:

- CPU load is > 95% VALUE = 97.23
- CPU load is > 95% VALUE = 96.23
- CPU load is > 95% VALUE = 98.23
- CPU load is > 95% VALUE = 94.23

Of course, these are different alerts, and I have configured repeat_interval = 24h. So each of them I receive once at 24 hours.

My idea is to stop receiving additional alerts until the CPU load become less 94% because I have these alerts in TeamWork and don't need more than one per 24 hours.

My alertmanager.conf

```yaml
global:
  resolve_timeout: 1440m
  telegram_api_url: "https://api.telegram.org"
  http_config:
    follow_redirects: true

templates:
  - '/opt/prometheus/etc/rules/alertmanager_notifications_telegram.tmpl'

route:
  group_by: ['instance']
  group_wait: 60s
  group_interval: 5s
  repeat_interval: 719h
  receiver: 'emaildevelopers'

  routes:
  - receiver: 'telegram'
    group_by: [instance, alertname, service]
    group_wait: 10s
    repeat_interval: 24h
    continue: true
    matchers:
    - severity="critical"
  
  - receiver: 'emailteamworker'
    group_by: [instance]
    group_wait: 10s
    repeat_interval: 24h
    continue: true
    matchers:
    - receiver="email"
  
inhibit_rules:
- equal: ['instance']
  source_matchers:
    - severity = critical
  target_matchers:
    - "severity =~ warning|info"

receivers:
  - name: 'telegram'
    telegram_configs:
    - api_url: 'https://api.telegram.org'
    ...
  
  - name: 'emailteamworker'
    email_configs:
    - to: 'xxx@tasks.teamwork.com'
      from: 'XX YY <devops@domain.com>'
      smarthost: 'smtp.sendgrid.net:587'
      hello: 'domain.com'
      auth_username: 'apikey'
      auth_password: 'SG.cvfg'
      send_resolved: false
      headers:
    ...
```

Alert rule

```yaml
  - name: Host and hardware node-exporter
    ...
      - alert: HostHighCpuLoad95
        expr: 100 - (avg by(instance) (rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[10m])) * 100) > 95
        for: 1m
        labels:
          severity: critical
          receiver: email
        annotations:
          summary: "Host high CPU load &gt; 95% instance {{ $labels.instance }} for last 60 minutes"
          description: "CPU load is &gt; 95%  VALUE = {{ $value | humanize }}  LABELS = {{ $labels }}"
    ...
```

Comment: Weird, you should receive just one alert on each 24h. Are they from different instances? Please add the alert rule.

Comment: Yes, it is for one instance but for the last 10 minutes.

Comment: Ok, so you're sure these 4 alerts have the same labels, correct? The alert is not flipping between "firing" and "resolved", is it?

Comment: Yes, labels are the same. But I'm not sure if the alert is not flipping between "firing" and "resolved." 
I have configured "send resolve." But may you please tell me if there is a better solution to check?

Comment: Are you receiving any "resolved" alerts? Could you edit your answer adding the complete alert (summary and description)?

Comment: Yes, I have got some "resolved." It looks CPU was busy for 96%, then became 80%, then again above 97%. 

I think it needs to improve the alert's query to something like Zabbix. 

You can configure Zabbix a low value and time, after which an alert will be made as resolved. For example, send an alert above 95% and send a resolve when less 70% for 15 minutes. Is it possible with Prometheus?

Comment: I don't think so